# How to make y' = 1/(2x - y^2) into a Bernoulli equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y' = \frac{1}{2x-y^2}$$

I thought of everything but couldn't find a working answer. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Write it as $\frac{dx}{dy}=…$ and use an integrating factor

Comment: My teacher insists to not use it because he didn't show us that yet.

Comment: The only equations that transform into Bernoulli are Riccati equations. Is there some error in the formula, $y'=\frac1{2x}-y^2$ would be a Riccati equation, but without obvious particular solution, $y'=\frac12x-y^2$ would not be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:-

You can write $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}$$
For the given equation
$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2x-y^2}$

The Bernoulli equation can be written using the above fact as

$$\frac{dx}{dy} -2x = -y^2$$